# keeping track of a series of simple multiple choice web form answers

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

**This is the code I'm trying to use**, which seems logical. But doesn't seem to be working.

```
MyAsFileName.prototype.getTotalScore = function() {
 var totalScore = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++) {
  totalScore += allQuestions[i].getCalculatedScore();
  if (currentModule.allQuestions[i].parent.questionCorrect == true) {
   knowledgePoints++;
  } else {
   knowledgePoints--;
  }
 }
 debugLog("Total score: " + totalScore);
 debugLog(knowledgePoints);
 return totalScore;
}
```

I have `allQuestions` defined as below:

```
var allQuestions    = Array();
```

I have `knowledgePoints` defined as:

```
 this.knowledgePoints = 10;
```

I have `questionCorrect` defined as:

```
this.questionCorrect = false;
```

---

**Second fresh attempt** made with new class as answer below suggested *(commented out for now until I figure out how to get working)*:

```
// package
// {
/*public class Quiz {
 //public
 var knowledgePoints: int = 10;
 //public
 var allQuestions: Array = new Array;
 //public
 var questionCorrect: Boolean = false;

 //public
 function getTotalScore(): int {
  var totalScore: int = 0; 

  for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++) {
   totalScore += allQuestions[i].getCalculatedScore();

   if (currentModule.allQuestions[i].parent.questionCorrect) {
    knowledgePoints++;
   } else {
    knowledgePoints--;
   }
  }
  debugLog("Total score: " + totalScore);
  debugLog(knowledgePoints);

  return totalScore;
 }
}*/
//}
```

This code above outputs two errors in flash console:

***Error 1. Attribute used outside of class.***

***Error 2. 'Int' could not be loaded.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a weird (and actually non-AS3 way) way to do this. Instead of creating a unnamed closure which refers weird variables from who-knows where, you should make it a normal AS3 class, something like that (in a file named Quiz.as):

```
package
{
    public class Quiz
    {
        public var knowledgePoints:int = 10;
        public var allQuestions:Array = new Array;
        public var questionCorrect:Boolean = false;

        public function getTotalScore():int
        {
            var totalScore:int = 0;

            // Your code does not explain how you will that Array.
            // It is initially an empty Array of length 0.
            for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++)
            {
                totalScore += allQuestions[i].getCalculatedScore();

                if (currentModule.allQuestions[i].parent.questionCorrect)
                {
                    knowledgePoints++;
                }
                else
                {
                    knowledgePoints--;
                }
            }

            // Not sure what it is.
            debugLog("Total score: " + totalScore);
            debugLog(knowledgePoints);

            return totalScore;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this approach. What was your comment '// Your code does not explain how you will that Array.'?

Comment: with the 'debugLog' I was trying to print the current total

Comment: @X-RaySpecs there are some pieces of your code that probably makes sense for you because you know the bigger picture. So I put comments to make that clear.

Comment: Ah, Ok. I am gettting 2 errors :/ one with line 'public class Quiz' - states "Attribute used outside class' and 'The class or interface 'int' could not be loaded.'

Comment: @X-RaySpecs Which means you are using AS1/2 rather then AS3.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry I removed the AS3 tag.

Comment: Is there anything I could tweak to try and still use this?

Comment: @X-RaySpecs Why AS1/2 at all? It is slow, it lacks integrity and flexibility, it is almost 10 years since outdated.

Comment: I do not make decisions my friend. But yes, I agree.

Comment: @X-RaySpecs Well then. That's quite a Ziggurat for you to climb. Trace every single reference inside the function, that's what I'd do **16 years ago when AS1 was still fresh**, some of the fields should probably be referenced through **this** because they are undefined otherwise. I cannot tell which ones because it was far too long ago when I composed my last AS1 script.