# gather total score of quiz questions with new .as class (2 errors currently)

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I currently created a new actionScript class, called `Quiz.as`

```
// package
// {
//    public class Quiz
//    {
        public var knowledgePoints:int = 10;
        public var allQuestions:Array = new Array;
        public var questionCorrect:Boolean = false;

        public function getTotalScore():int
        {
          //  var totalScore:int = 0;

              var totalScore = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++)
            {
                totalScore += allQuestions[i].getCalculatedScore();

                if (currentModule.allQuestions[i].parent.questionCorrect)
                {
                    knowledgePoints++;
                }
                else
                {
                    knowledgePoints--;
                }
            }
            debugLog("Total score: " + totalScore);
            debugLog(knowledgePoints);

            return totalScore;
        }
//    }
//}
```

This solution derived from my original question at: [keeping track of a series of simple multiple choice web form answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43897561/keeping-track-of-a-series-of-simple-multiple-choice-web-form-answers/43898050?noredirect=1#comment74831426_43898050)

But now with the above code I am getting errors in flash console. My latest attempt to fix these errors are with the commented out regions above.

---

**Error 1.** Attribute used outside of class. 
*So I comment out first couple lines, but error continues to point to whatever line is exposed first.*

**Error 2.** 'Int' could not be loaded.

Thanks for any advice,

Comment: Do you have this code on a timeline frame?

Comment: are you using AS2?  (you've tagged it as such).   The code you've shared is AS3 and thus will produce many errors if compiling as AS2.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find an as2 solution for the above.

Comment: Use AS3 instead I say, AS2 has different syntax as is obsolete as heck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is likely the result of using the above code on the timeline in AnimateCC/FlashPro.

Class files (and their corresponding attributes like public/private) need to be in their own actionscript (.as) file.

To create a class file in AnimateCC,  go to *file -> new* and choose **ActionScript 3.0 Class**.  Give it the class name of `Quiz` (so it matches what you've declared in your code)

Replace the default code with the class file code from your question (you'll need to restore those commented out lines too)

Save the file in the same directory as your .fla

To use your new class file in the timeline, you'd do something like this:

```
var quiz:Quiz = new Quiz(); //make an instance of your custom class

quiz.allQuestions.push(whateverAQuestionIs); //add a question to your array

trace(quiz.getTotalScore()); //trace out the total score
```

---

If you want to use that code in the timeline and forgo using a class file,  you'll just need to remove the 4 `public` keywords (in addition to the lines you've already commented out)

Comment: Thanks for your input

Comment: Hey, how are you using 'trace(quiz.getTotalScore()); //trace out the total score'? Where is that defined?

Comment: `trace` is a top-level function built into FlashPlayer so it can be used anywhere in the code

Comment: Thanks! What does it do exactly?

Comment: It sends text to the output window for debugging purposes.   similar to `console.log()` in other languages.